# MS-Teams Deeplink to start conversation with bot

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any way to start conversation with bot in ms-teams via deeplinks?

I already searching within https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links and trying some links and use it with bot appsID but always failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Memew You could get the link to the bot conversation by right clicking on the Microsoft Teams channel added in the bot framework where you have created your bot.
[image]

Comment: is the bot needed published first?

Comment: You don't need the bot to be installed in Teams to use the deeplink

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @Gousia-MSFT's answer, to find the link I went to Microsoft Azure > Bot Services > Channels and you will see the "Connect to Channels" page.

[image: Azure Bot Service Screenshot]